# Error : cannot open display : 11.0

Tags: proxy, kali-linux

im using kali linux and im trying to do a proxychain

the tor is open if im not root and use for example proxychains firefox [www.duckduck.go](http://www.duckduck.go) its working but if i sudo -i and im root and use the same command its showing me this

[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :11.0

Answer (score 0):

You should not run firefox as root anyways, it is a massive security risk.

Also firefox could bypass proxychains, revealing your IP address.
In addition to that, using a browser other than torbrowser gives you a relatively unique fingerprint, more so if you install extensions.

You should always use the torbrowser instead.
You can install the torbrowser on linux via

`sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher`